# Adding Outlook appointment using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook, exchange-server, icalendar

I am creating an ASP.Net MVC project where users will add Outlook appointments to other users calendars. I other words; I wish for a user of my web app to be able to add an appointment directly in another persons calendar. This means sending it via email with no need for the receiver to accept it. It should be as if the receiver actually created it himself in Outlook.

Is this even possible to do?

The web app is hosted outside the customers network.

Best regards
Pål Eilertsen

Comment: Do you have access to the Exchange server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an ICS file that the user can double click and store the appointment. If multiple users, it can be sent to others. If you can get access to their exchange server (sounds like you can't), as SLaks asked, you can use something like this (http://goo.gl/G2nrd). If you have no access to Exchange directly, the ICS file format will allow the user to add the appointment.

If you want an example of an ics file (other than a Google search), sign up for a Microsoft event and click the "add to outlook" button. The fortunate thing about this methodology is it can also work with other mail/calendar applications that use the format.

Comment: Well, creating an ICS file is what I have already done. The thing is that I cannot relay on the receiver to open and save the appoinment. The booker actually needs to see the appoinment in the receivers calendar straight away. Is it possible to create a ICS file that can be clicked by the booker but saved to another persons calendar (of cource his calendar needs to be shared).

Comment: By the way; could a possible solution be to have a service exposed at the customer that could actually add the appointment directly to Exchange. And then my web app could connect to this service.

Comment: @Pål This is certainly an option if this is a service people sign up for or similar. It can also be used in shrinkwrap ware, but note that you will often end up with lots of customer support forcing this type of change on the client side.